# Canceling drag because exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException': attempt to insert nil object

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I try to drag & drop an object from a `NSOutlineView` to another, it usually works, but sometimes it fails for some objects. I get the message:

```
*** Canceling drag because exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' (reason '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]') was raised during a dragging session
```

**I've found out that this happens when I first drag the item over another row of the same table (without releasing it), and then drag to the new table.**

This is the content of the draggedItems in the last function I can check during the dragging:

```
- (id <NSPasteboardWriting>)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView pasteboardWriterForItem:(id)item
{
    CBCollectible *collectible = [item representedObject];
    return [[collectible UniqueID] stringValue];
}

- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
    draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
       endedAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
          operation:(NSDragOperation)operation
{
    //CBDebug(@"end draggingLeaderIndex %i", session.draggingLeaderIndex);
}

- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
    draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
   willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
           forItems:(NSArray *)draggedItems
{
    FreeAndNil(theDraggedItems);
    theDraggedItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:draggedItems];
    [session.draggingPasteboard setData:[NSData data] forType:MAIN_VIEW_PASTEBOARD_TYPE];
}

- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
updateDraggingItemsForDrag:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo
{
}
```

Output Log:

```
NSLog(@"draggedItems %@", draggedItems);
<__NSArrayM 0x31fa0f0>(
<NSTreeControllerTreeNode: 0x1d23750>, child nodes {}
)
```

**UPDATE**: Dragging registration

```
[outlineView1 registerForDraggedTypes:@[MAIN_VIEW_PASTEBOARD_TYPE, NSStringPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType]];
[outlineView2 registerForDraggedTypes:@[MAIN_VIEW_PASTEBOARD_TYPE, NSStringPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType]];
```

Comment: What does logging `objects` display on the line right before the crash?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code that implements the dragging.

Comment: @rebello95 Since the crash it's occurring in the drag&drop API, I cannot check the line right before. But I can check what's the dragged item in the datasource function - outlineView:draggingSession:willBeginAtPoint:forItems:. I've copied the log in the question.

Comment: @Nickkk Which code more precisely? The methods of the receiving NSOutlineView are not invoked when the dragging fails. So if you want I can copy the methods of the source outlineView. But these are working well when I drag an object in the table itself.

Comment: In any case I've copied the the content of the called function above.

Comment: What is `FreeAndNil` supposed to do? Aren't you trying to init an array with a nil object as the error says?

Comment: @Nickkk Well, I'm just dragging drop from an outline view to another one. I don't see where this nil object is inserted because the exception is thrown from APIs code. Also the drag drop works well in between the same outline view with the same objects, so they can't be nil. (I've also inspected them by checking the content of the NSTreeController).

Comment: Could you please try commenting out that line and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @Nickkk which line? The console logging?

Comment: `FreeAndNil(theDraggedItems);`

Comment: @Nickkk Sorry Nickkk I haven't read correctly your old comment. Now I see you were asking me what FreeAndNil. It's just [theDraggedItems release]; theDraggedItems = nil;

Comment: @Nickkk I've commented out and nothing changes. Indeed I've just introduced a memory leak by doing that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that `theDraggedItems` and `draggedItems` are different variables.

Comment: What is the type you are returning in `outlineView:pasteboardWriterForItem:`? It seems like you are returning a `NSString`, which doesn't conform to the `NSPasteboardWriting` protocol. Maybe try implementing `outlineView:writeItems:toPasteboard:` instead.

Comment: @Nickkk I can read from documentation that: The Cocoa framework classes NSString, NSAttributedString, NSURL, NSColor, NSSound, NSImage, and NSPasteboardItem implement this protocol.

Comment: I have replaced `outlineView:pasteboardWriterForItem:` with `outlineView:writeItems:toPasteboard:` but it's the same. However I noticed that sometimes it works few times before to get the exception.

Comment: Sorry, my fault again. In the `NSPasteboardWriting` documentation I can read that `NSString` conforms to it, but in the `NSString` documentation this protocol is not mentioned. Strange ...

Comment: Why don't you try something like `[session.draggingPasteboard setData:[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:draggedItems] forType:MAIN_VIEW_PASTEBOARD_TYPE]` instead of using `theDraggedItems`?

Comment: @Nickkk I tried to use that line, but what I get is: `[NSTreeControllerTreeNode encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` on that line

Comment: @Nickkk Sorry for the delay. I've some updates: see the bold text in the question.

Comment: Could you please show what code you wrote to register your outline view for dragging?

Comment: @Nickkk I've added to the question

Comment: For some reason I'm unable to register my sample outline views for dragging operations ... So I'll just ask you to try out this code after `FreeAndNil`: `theDraggedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[draggedItems count]]; for (NSTreeNode *node in draggedItems) { [theDraggedItems addObject:[node representedObject]]; }`

Comment: @Nickkk You mean replacing the code in outlineView:draggingSession:willBeginAtPoint:forItems: right? I've replaced it, and it crashes. And it crashes because I'm adding the representedObject instead of its tree node, so I'm changing the objects in my tree. Why did you suggest me to use that code?

Comment: I don't get what you mean ... You're not changing the tree at all. With this code you should be able to use the archiver as I suggested above.

Comment: @Nickkk 1. But in the code you sent me you are not using the archiver, you are still using theDraggedItems, right? 2. What I meant is that you are passing the [node representedObject] instead of the node object.

Comment: I used `theDraggedItems` because you need an array to be archived (you could declare a new one if you prefer). You somehow have to extract the representedObjects from the tree because, as you've seen, it's not possible to archive the tree directly, so you'll have to think of a data structure that will allow you to rebuild the tree when unarchiving the data. I just added everything to an array so that you would be able to see if this approach works or not.

Comment: @Nickkk but why do I need to archive, I'm using an instance variable to store the dragged items and it works well among the 2 outline views. My problem, as specified above, is that when I drag these items first over another row of the same table and then over the other table I get that error.

Comment: If instead I drag them from table1 directly over table2 it works good

Comment: It's merely a suggestion. I don't know whether it will resolve the problem, but I think it's worth testing it.

Comment: @Nickkk I see, but I really need to drag the node and not its representedObject, because the tables are populates with nodes, if I get rid of the node, I cannot complete the dragging because the object is lost.

Comment: Then I can only suggest to implement `outlineView:acceptDrop:item:childIndex:` and `outlineView:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedChildIndex:`. At least that's what I did in some code of mine to implemented drag-and-drop for a `NSTableView`.

Comment: @Nickkk I've implemented them. I didn't post the code because when it fails, it fails before those functions are called. When it succeed, those functions work correctly.

Comment: Please post the stack trace.